# Distinguish SendKeys from Real user/keyboard keystrokes

Tags: vb.net, keypress, keydown, sendkeys, keyup

I am trying to develop a typing speed calculator app in vb.net for windows...

The problem I am trying to solve is rejecting sendkeys i.e. I would like the user to only enter text from the keyboard.

Is there any way it can detect sendkeys from other application or autotypers and clears the textbox?

Things I have tried:

Tried to set timer on the events occurring to detect the strokes from a sendkeys(did not work)

Tried the low level hook mentioned in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx
in vb by running the main module by disabling the visual styles and running my form from the main so as to set the hook.(did not work)

Even tried other hooks from codeprojects.

The idea that i am working right now is that the user has to lose focus from the form to activate the application that will send the keystrokes. I think to change the focus from the text box to a button or something so that when another app tries to sendkeys it wont be able to do so.

Comment: I did try the code in the link... and it does not work and that I also tried a few other code examples all failed to work hence i am posted the above question.

Comment: Your question does not indicate that you've made any effort to solve or research the problem before posting here. If you've done so, [edit] your question to show what you've tried and explain how it's not working to suit your needs.

Comment: Sendkeys was designed to add messages to the queue, like a keyboard. Therefore you cannot determine which is which. BTW, your focus idea would not work either because I could activate my app with hotkeys or using the system tray, which does not cause your app to loose focus. The closest you could come is to see what assemblies are loaded in every running application and see if one of them has the same assembly used for SendKeys, but this will return a lot of false-positives.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of detecting keystrokes from the other applications, you may be able to use some interprocess communication such as [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).